# MediaStore list all songs from specific path

Tags: android, mediastore

I want to get all the songs from one specific path on the device.
in a example i want to get all the songs from one specific folder "music" from path: "/mnt/sdcard/music/" , what i need to change in my code to able to achieve this?
i have this method that get all the songs from the device:

```
public ArrayList<Song> scanAllSongsOnDevice(Context c)
    {
        ContentResolver musicResolver = c.getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String col[] ={android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);


        if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            // clear  list to prevent duplicates
            songsList = new ArrayList<>();

            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int isMusicColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC);
            int duration = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);

            //add songs to list
            do
            {
                String filePath = musicCursor.getString(musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                // check if the file is a music and the type is supported
                if (musicCursor.getInt(isMusicColumn) != 0 && filePath != null && (FileExtensionFilter.checkValidExtension(filePath)) && musicCursor.getInt(duration) > 0)
                {
                    int thisId = musicCursor.getInt(idColumn);
                    String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                    Song song = new Song();
                    song.setId(thisId);
                    if(!thisArtist.equals("<unknown>"))
                    {
                        song.setArtist(thisArtist);
                        song.setTitle(thisTitle);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        song.setArtist("");
                        song.setTitle("");
                    }
                    song.setSongPath(filePath);
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    song.setFileName(file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                    songsList.add(song);
                }
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else  // if we don't have any media in the folder that we selected set NO MEDIA
        {
            addNoSongs();
        }

        musicCursor.close();

        if(songsList.size() == 0)
        {
            addNoSongs();
        }

        Collections.sort(songsList, new Comparator<Song>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Song song, Song song2)
            {
                int compare = song.getTitle().compareTo(song2.getTitle());
                return ((compare == 0) ? song.getArtist().compareTo(
                        song2.getArtist()) : compare);
            }
        });

        return songsList;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to modify your `audioCursor` like

```
audioCursor = audioResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
            new String[] {"%YOUR_SPECIFIC_FOLDER_NAME%"},  null);
```

Hope it will help you...

Thanks

Comment: i don't want to get specific file name. i want to get all the songs from a path

Comment: @AlexTheLion What is your destination folder name? Just replace it with that and you will get all audios from that folder.

Comment: not helped ,if i type "music" it will get all the songs from that folder and sub folders and thats not what i want. i want get all the songs from one specific folder

Comment: what if my specific folder is hidden folder ? how do I fetch from specific hidden folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add the data of you songs to system's media store by MediaScanner.

```
    String scanDir = null;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        scanDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "music";
    } else {
        // sdcard is not available
    }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), 
            new String[] { scanDir },
            new String[] { "audio/*" }, 
            new OnScanCompletedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                }
            });
```

This will send a broadcast intent to framework, the framework will scan the directory you specify and add the scanned result to system media store database.

After that, you can access the data by contentresolver like the code you pasted.

Comment: That's not what i need. i want to get list of songs like in my method "scanAllSongsOnDevice"

Answer (score -1):

Change your `filePath` variable to this:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/music";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public ArrayList<File> findSong(File root) {

        ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = root.listFiles();    // All file and folder automatic collect

        for (File singleFile : files) {
            if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
                al.addAll(findSong(singleFile)); //Recursively call
            } else {
                if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    al.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return al;
    }
```

onCreate:

```
final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        items = new String[mySongs.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
            //  toast(mySongs.get(i).getName().toString());
            //  items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString();
            items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3", "");
        }
```